# "ionic build ios" don't show build succeeded?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run "ionic build ios" command from my project directory, it does lots of operations (I can see lots of console messages) but at the end, it does not show "BUILD SUCCEEDED" as it does in the normal case.

After executing above command also there is no any failure message in whole logs, so how should I know that build is done with success?

Last Readable Console message :

```
CompileC /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gtzhmtcrepuouaeswxkesmrucnih/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.o Classes/Public/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/username/Projects/EQLatest/myapp-credit-report-mobile-app/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Versions of tools my machine :
cordova --> 6.4.0,
ionic --> 2.1.4,

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: @SurajRao please have look at updated question

Comment: maybe add --debug to your command line to get more details on what's going on?

Comment: Did you get any solution?